# Problem with apt held broken packages

Tags: apt, 22.04, dpkg, clamav

I'm trying to install clamav and when I'm running `sudo apt-get install clamav clamav-daemon -y`

The output is:

```
root@server:/etc/apt# apt-get install clamav
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libclamav9 : Depends: libtfm1 (>= 0.13) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And this (which gives blank output):

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

And none of these commands helped.

I also checked my `sources.list`, and it seems to be ok. I also tried to remove this packages, but I only have "these packages are not installed". Any suggestions?

Comment: @ArturMeinild I already have been on this page, and nothing helped me. For example, when I try to install aptitude, I have 3 more broken packages.

Comment: The package mentioned is available for *jammy* (22.04); ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libtfm1 which meets the requirements... Return to basics; ie. `sudo apt update` or examine your sources, are any missing?  you've corrupted your sources with details from other OSes or releases? etc   (your installed packaging being https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/libclamav9 if using Ubuntu repositories)

Comment: You've tagged your question as being about a Debian/Ubuntu workflow issue??  How is that related?  (ie. why tag Debian-Ubuntu workflow?)